# Can I create this in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

I have table like following:

```
Locaiton Val1   Val2
L1       1      2
L1       0      5
L1       4      1
L1       7      8
L2       1      3
L2       6      1
L2       2      11
L2       0      2
L2       6      3
L2       8      4
L2       1      1
```

I want to convert it like following: 
    Location    Val1    Val2

```
Location    Val1            Val2
L1          1,0,4,7,1,6     2,5,1,8,3,1
L2          2,0,6,7,1       11,2,3,4,1
```

Comment: You need to use `STUFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stuff as below

```
select [Location], stuff ((
select ',' + val1 from #Table1 where [Location] = t.[Location] 
for xml path('')
),1,1,'') as Val1,
stuff ((
select ',' + val2 from #Table1 where [Location] = t.[Location] 
for xml path('')
),1,1,'') as Val2
from #Table1 t
group by [Location]
```

If it is sql server 2017 or vnext you can use string_agg

```
select [Location], val1 = string_agg(val1,','), val2 = string_agg(val2,',')
    from #table1 
group by [Location]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain.  You need to do the string concatenation trick twice:

```
select t.location,
       stuff( (select ',' + cast(val1 as varchar(255))
               from t t2
               where t2.location = t.location
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as val1s,
       stuff( (select ',' + cast(val2 as varchar(255))
               from t t2
               where t2.location = t.location
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as val2s
from (select distinct location from t) t;
```

Note that the ordering of the ids in each list is indeterminate.  This is how SQL works.  If you want them in a particular order, you need to add an `ORDER BY` to the subqueries.  Your sample data has no obvious column for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can it by the following query,

```
    SELECT  Location
        ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+CAST(Val1 AS NVARCHAR)
                FROM YourTable t
                WHERE t.Location = Location),1,1,'')    AS Val1
        ,STUFF((    SELECT DISTINCT ','+CAST(Val2 AS NVARCHAR)
            FROM YourTable t
            WHERE t.Location = Location),1,1,'')    AS Val2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Location
```